# Lenses with interdependent (simultaneous) updates

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Lets say I have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Control.Lens

data T a b = T { _foo :: a
               , _bar :: a -> b
               }

makeLenses ''T
```

`a` appears in both `foo` and `bar`, so updates have to be "simulatenous", as it were. This is possible without lenses:

```
eg1 :: T a (b -> c) -> b -> T (a, b) c
eg1 (T foo bar) b = T (foo, b) (uncurry bar)
```

But how can I do this with lenses? The following doesn't work with an occurs check:

```
eg :: T a (b -> c) -> b -> T (a, b) c
eg t b = t & foo %~ (, b) & bar %~ uncurry
```

Comment: You don't do that with lenses.

Comment: There are a few odd things going on here. First, note that you can't make a lens for the `a` in `a -> b`. Second note that you can't make a lens for `Tuple a = Tuple a a`, but you can make a *traversal*.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson can you expand? What would the `Tuple a = Tuple a a` traversal be?

Comment: Traversals are like lenses except that they "focus on" 0 or more "spots". So you can write a traversal which focuses on each half of a homogenous Tuple.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson but in this case one `a` is in positive and one in negative position.

Comment: Yeah, and you simple cannot write a lens over a type in a negative position. There's no "there" to be focused on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this using the automatically generated lenses for `T`. If you want to stretch things a bit, you can first define

```
data T' a b c = T' { _foo' :: c, _bar' :: a -> b}

tt :: Iso (T a b) (T a' b') (T' a b a) (T' a' b' a')
tt = dimap (\(T x g) -> T' x g) (fmap (\(T' x g) -> T x g))
```

Then you can (automatically) build type-changing lenses for `T'` and use `tt` to use them to modify values of type `T a b` through the isomorphism.

For example, rearranging the arguments a bit, you can write

```
eg :: b -> T a (b -> c) -> T (a, b) c
eg b = over tt $ (foo' %~ (,b)) . (bar' %~ uncurry)
```

Another approach that will likely be better if you don't need to fuss around with `T` too much is to define it as a `newtype` around `T'`:

```
newtype T a b = T { getT :: T' a b a }
```

Then you can skip the `Iso` and just compose things. Rearranging the arguments the same way,

```
eg' :: b -> T a (b -> c) -> T (a, b) c
eg' b = T . (foo' %~ (,b)) . (bar' %~ uncurry) . getT
```

Comment: `over` can be used directly in lieu of `from` bracketing: `supply y = over tt (\(T' x f) -> T' (x, y) (uncurry f))`

Comment: @duplode, actually, I can't seem to make that work at all. I've backed off to the bracketing approach, but if you can show how to do it better, I'm all ears.

Comment: It seems the only issue is that `tt` should be `Iso (T a b) (T a' b') (T' a b a) (T' a' b' a')`; that is, `a` should be allowed to change as well. That should be enough to allow you to define `eg` with a single `over` then.

Comment: @duplode, at last! I also worked in the lensy modification to `T'`, which was the actual purpose of setting up that `Iso`.